# Changing Background Image in IE 10 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

I'm developing a web site these days, I developed a option for my site so users can change the background image.

I previously used windows 7 and XP, changing background image worked on both win 7 and XP's Internet Explorer but recently I moved to windows 8 which comes with IE 10, when I test my site with IE 10, changing background images doesn't work.

why are these guys changing these stuff? I shouldn't even care about this matter but still there are people who use IE. :(

here is my code

```
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + picurl + ")";
```

Any idea how it can be done with IE 10 ?

Comment: use jQuery, it'll reduce the browser specific issues.

Comment: What's exactly picurl ? A string holding an absolute path to an image file ?

Comment: try with quotes : `"url(\"" + picurl + "\")";`

Comment: @AramKocharyan : thanks, can you provide me any reference?

Comment: @dystroy : picurl depends on what picture user choose. I must say that this works on all the other browsers. :(

Comment: @NaviGamage http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is working for me in IE10. Incase your url has a space character,
Try this

```
body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + picurl + "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

If the image is already known in advance, it would reduce maintenance if you specified it in a class in a CSS file, and simply added a new class. In jQuery:

```
$(body).addClass('my-bgd-class');
```

However, since you're using a variable, you would do:

```
$(body).css('background-image', 'url("' + picurl + '")');
```

Comment: The problem still stands and jQuery is in my humble opinion a better solution. The OP may not be aware of it and so I've provided the code for comparison if they want to try it. It would be a different case if they specifically mentioned they didn't want to use jQuery as a solution.

Comment: The class solution is a good solution, I would have +1 if it had a non jQuery solution added. A developer does not need to add 40ishK to add a class. [I use jQuery, but not everyone does]

Comment: For jQuery I suspect you'd need to put the code in `$(function(...))` or `$(document).ready(function() {...})` else body may not be ready when the script loads in head. But if you're not using jQuery and don't need to, use pure JS.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've quoted works fine for me.

I've done a jsFiddle to prove it -- http://jsfiddle.net/Ryavz/

```
var picurl = "http://static.travelblog.org/Wallpaper/pix/waterfall_desktop_background-1600x1200.jpg";  //just a random image I found on the web
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+picurl+")";
```

The above code works the same for me in IE10 and other browsers.

If there is a specific problem with your site in IE10, it's not with the code you quoted.

You probably should be adding quotes to the `url()` style parameter, in case the URL has a space or a bracket or something like that in it, but other than that, your code is fine, and it works for me in all browsers with or without quotes.